# Declare global debug variable

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, ionic-framework

I'd like to import and use the following function for debugging:

```
export function debug(string) {
  if(debugMode) { console.log(`DEBUG: ${string}`) }
}
```

but I don't know how to make a variable, like `debugMode` globally accessible. Is this even possible with TypeScript? I would simply set it in `app.component.ts` to `true` or `false` so the function only works when I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it that way

**utils.module.ts**

```
export class Config
{
  constructor(public readonly debugMode) {  }
}
export let GlobalConfig  = new Config(true);

export function debug(string) {
  if(GlobalConfig.debugMode) { console.log(`DEBUG: ${string}`); }
}
```

**Your component**

```
import {debug, GlobalConfig} from '../utils.module';
//..
debug('test');
if(GlobalConfig.debugMode)
    console.log('In debug mode');
```

You just need to import that function and the conf variable when you need to use it

If you just export and import `debugMode`, any class can modify it (not sure if it's what you want)